# Oracle persistent column alias

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am an Oracle end user, not a database developer or admin.

Our database has some typos in column names, similar to a column being named `ADRESS2` instead of `ADDRESS2`

I have to use these columns in my queries, and it's hard to remember which typo applies to which column.  Also, I'm kind of <s>anal</s> persnickety about the way this makes my code look (not so professional).

I suspect there is no chance of getting these columns actually renamed in production -- it would be a low priority with lots of dependencies.

What is the best practice in this situation?

I can think of a couple options:

- add comments that the typo is intentional
- wrap the table with a `select(bad_name good_name, * from table)`
- create a view based on the above

But is there any way to do something like:

```
DECLARE address2 CHAR(8) := 'adress2';
```

And use in a query, but returning the values of `ADRESS2` instead of the char "adress2".

The desired solution would be a practice that:

- wouldn't increase the complexity of the query
- would be recognized by developers as a response to a situation where column names are unwieldy or misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think about the only legitimate response is a view.  If I were in your situation, I'd fix the column typos.  Failing that, I would create a view.

But, something in your question makes me think that you're willing to consider something more "out there", so here it is:

```
alter table sample_table add address2 
    invisible generated always as ( addres2 || '') virtual;
```

This is very likely to not impact any of your applications, as nothing will see the `ADDRESS2` column unless they explicitly ask for it.

But, it makes it available for you persnickity types.

Keep in mind that the function `ADDRES2 || ''` means your queries won't use indexes on the columns you access this way.

Repeat: I would change the column names or make a view.

Comment: Apologies to the OP -- I see you are on 11g.  No `INVISIBLE` columns for you (it's a 12c feature).

Comment: No need for it to be invisible. You can just have it as `alter table sample_table add address2 generated always as ( addres2 || '') virtual;` - this will work on 11g Release 1.

Comment: True, but making it `INVISIBLE` significantly decreases the risk of breaking existing systems.  If the column is not `INVISIBLE`, any code accessing columns via `SELECT *` (bad practice, but it happens), will include the new column as well.